# Android studio with Flutter. How to set it right?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to set my android studio for the whole day. My flutter doctor is lighting all green, but IDE is not working properly.

When I start a new project, I am missing IOS and android files. Also, I am not able to run my app in virtual machine.

**My IDE**
[image: my]

**How it should be**

[image: tutorial]

Comment: did you create a project using `flutter create` command?

Comment: No. That was not in the tutorial i used. Should i use that command in the file where my final project should be?

Comment: Your project is missing lib and ios folder, consider deleting the project and create it again with `File->New->New Flutter project` or with `flutter create [name_of_project]` command

Comment: I used the File->New->New Flutter project but thi is what i got.

Comment: Okay, I tried the second method and this is what happend:                                 Flutter failed to copy
C:\src\flutter_windows_2.5.2-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\templates\app_shared\android.tmpl\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png to
C:\Users\proch\OneDrive\Plocha\serpent\test\test\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png due to unknown
error. The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current
user.

Comment: I tried to give permissions to Flutter SDK but it is still not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.